# access dictionary with unicode keys from django template

Tags: unicode, django-templates

I have a dictionary with unicode keys (the dictionary is being pulled from a mongo db). when i render it in a template, i cant access it using the keys since there is no way to generate unicode string in the template (None that i know of)

here is my code: (abbreviated)

### views.py

```
context={
         'title':'Mytitle',
         'options'={
                    u'A':u'1st option',
                    u'A':u'1st option',
                    u'A':u'1st option', 
                    u'A':u'1st option',
                    u'A':u'1st option'
         }
}      
return render(request,'trial.html',context)
```

### trial.html

```
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for i in 'ABCDE' %}
    <div>{{options.i}}</div>
</body>
```

all i want is to show the values in option in alphabetic order of the keys. If that can be done in any other way which doesn't need to solve this unicode issue, I am happy. If there is any way to get ascii strings from mongo, that will solve it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your context is in dict format (your's has option=). You create a custom templatetag to sort the values in your options. i hope it helps.

```
# custom templatetag
@register.filter
def sort_by_key(options):
    # output of this is a list of tuples [('A', 'value1'), ('B', 'value2')]
    return sorted(options.items(), key=lambda s: s[0])

# Template
{% for option in options|sort_by_key %}
    <!-- here key=option.0 and value=option.1 -->
    <option id="{{ option.0 }}" value="{{ option.1 }}">{{ option.1 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```